# Apache BPEL -> Inovking rest service throws ode:Fault Timeout or execution error when waiting for response to MEX

Tags: apache, ode, bpel

I tried to test Apache ode bpel example given in below url. I am calling my own rest service (Spring) which returns string and no input arguments and I am testing only GET operation from below sample and removed PUT, POST and DELETE

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/bps/3.5.0/modules/samples/product/src/main/resources/bpel/2.0/UserRestProcess/

It is giving below exception while invoking the rest service.

```
ode:Fault Timeout or execution error when waiting for response to MEX {MyRoleMex#hqejbhcnphrcgnb4qit326 [Client hqejbhcnphrcgnb4qit325] calling {http://wso2.org/bps/sample}UserRestProcess.process(...)} java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Message exchange org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl$ResponseFuture@56797a58 timed out(120000 ms) when waiting for a response! org.apache.ode.axis2.OdeFault: Timeout or execution error when waiting for response to MEX {MyRoleMex#hqejbhcnphrcgnb4qit326 [Client hqejbhcnphrcgnb4qit325] calling {http://wso2.org/bps/sample}UserRestProcess.process(...)} java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Message exchange org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl$ResponseFuture@56797a58 timed out(120000 ms) when waiting for a response! at org.apache.ode.axis2.ODEService.onAxisMessageExchange(ODEService.java:169) at org.apache.ode.axis2.hooks.ODEMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(ODEMessageReceiver.java:69) at org.apache.ode.axis2.hooks.ODEMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(ODEMessageReceiver.java:52) at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114) at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176) at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145) at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92) at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have placed println statements in rest method and I see statements printed on console. Not sure what is happening after it returns from rest method. I already spent lot of time trying to figure out the root cause but no luck.

Any help on this is appreciated